# Hyperledger Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I was trying to start a network with:

`composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card`

But then I got this error:

```
Processing these Network Admins: 
    userName: admin

⠋ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: cannot get package for chaincode (tutorial-network:0.0.1)
Command failed
```

I already found the solution. Just sharing it here for people who get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was:

1) `composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna`

2) `composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card`

3) `composer card import --file networkadmin.card`

4) `composer network ping --card admin@tutorial-network`